# Enable ARC for theos build system

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, theos

I'm currently using the theos build system to write applications and tweaks for jailbroken iPhones. Is there a way for me to enable automatic reference counting for specific projects with theos?

I've Googled and tried to decipher the theos makefiles, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: I don't think it does, as ARC is supplied by the xcode compiler, and in Theos you have to hardcode everything. I would try iOSOpenDev, because you can make a tweak using Logos, and basically everything you would make with theos. Also, you can make those in Xcode, with code completion and ARC.

Comment: I *believe* that theos uses the same compiler as Xcode (llvm), and there should be a way to set up the compiler flags... I think. I've had lots of problems with iOSOpenDev (plus I prefer Sublime Text to Xcode as a code editor.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/Maxner/BrightnessFix/blob/master/Makefile

```
ARCHS=armv7 armv7s
TARGET_IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_VERSION = 6.0
TARGET_CC = xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang 
TARGET_CXX = xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang++
TARGET_LD = xcrun -sdk iphoneos clang++
SHARED_CFLAGS = -fobjc-arc

include theos/makefiles/common.mk

TWEAK_NAME = BrightnessFix
BrightnessFix_FILES = Tweak.xm
BrightnessFix_FRAMEWORKS = UIKit

include $(THEOS_MAKE_PATH)/tweak.mk
```

**SHARED_CFLAGS = -fobjc-arc**

is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not going to unaccept the above answer, because I suspect that this might just have to do with having different versions of `theos`, and the answer above definitely put me on the right track to finding what I needed. It turns out, at least for my version of `theos`, the environment variable to set is

```
ADDITIONAL_OBJCFLAGS = -fobjc-arc
```

(`ADDITIONAL_CFLAGS` is also an option, but I don't think there's an opportunity where it matters whether you enable ARC on straight-C code anyways).

Comment: glad we got on the correct path. i just cam across that make file as a demo. glad you figured it out.

Comment: @drewmm - Since I use iOSOpenDev, I can't see a make file for my project. Where do I put this?