# iOSOpenDev Enable ARC support for Logos tweak

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I build a static library for a non-jail broken phone with ARC Enabled. Works awesome. Then I build a Mobilesubstrate Logos Tweak with iOSOpenDev. It imports all same classes from static library. However it does not compile because ARC is enabled by default in new project. So I disable ARC and I am able to hook. But behavior of this tweak at times is weird. I doubt its ARC. I want to enable it. I have ready [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628108/enable-arc-for-theos-build-system/15629205#15629205) but doesn't help me much.

How can I enable ARC in iOSOpenDev project? Additional code for Logos is very simple

```
%hook UIApplication
-(void) sendEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{

[test ProcessEvent:event];//test is the static library classes imported directly in tweak

%orig;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I right understand, you can enable ARC like this:[image]

Or you can open your project and select Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC. This will start checking your code if it is ready for the conversion.

Or just read [this](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/everything-know-about-arc/) tutorial.

Comment: This is the flag for **disabling** ARC, not enabling it.  Remove the "no"

Comment: @Kirill - Thanks. It immediately stopped "weird" behavior of the app as soon as I enabled these flags( I did remove no from -fno-objc-arc). So looks like its working fine. Thx for your quick help.